# ASP.NET Core MacOS Connection string

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have issues establishing connection to my **mysql** server database on **MacOS** using Entity Framework Core for ASP.NET Core 2.0 project.

I am following this tutorial: https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/08/09/running-entity-framework-core-commands-rider/

My database is started as a default *mysql* server service on my MacBook running on localhost:3306 and has a User and Password for login. I can connect to the database from DataGrip and Terminal.

When I am running this command to establish connection and create DBContext:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=(mysql)\localhost;Database=edums_development;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -c EdumsDataContext
```

I am having an error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Undefined error: 0

Obviously meaning that my connection string is incorrect.

I don't know what exactly is incorrect and how should I include username and password to make it connected successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using wrong database driver `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`, this one is for MS SQL Server, what actually says the error

> error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections.

Try to use [`MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore/) instead

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=(mysql)\localhost;Database=edums_development;Trusted_Connection=True;" MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -c EdumsDataContext
```

Comment: It worked, I also did change `(mysql)\localhost` just into `localhost`

Comment: Glad to have been of help